# D3.js Dropdown: Removing Line Chart Data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3.js and Javascript and am using a dropdown to call different sets of data

I am having trouble figuring out **how to remove the old data before showing the new**.

Right now when you select option 2 from the dropdown list, it overlays option 1. I've read a little on the `.exit` and `.remove` functions but can't seem to figure out where in my code I need to place it.

I primarily based my line chart off of Mike Bostock's: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569

```css
date close
1-Jun-15 77.34
1-Jul-15 74.66
1-Aug-15 72.26
1-Sep-15 70.28
1-Oct-15 70.76
1-Nov-15 65.63
1-Dec-15 65.39
1-Jan-16 68.33
1-Feb-16 69.35
1-Mar-16 73.53
1-Apr-16 67.63
1-May-16 75.86
1-Jun-16 70.19
1-Jul-16 74.14
1-Aug-16 73.28
1-Sep-16 72.6
1-Oct-16 75.21
1-Nov-16 78.13
1-Dec-16 78.11
1-Jan-17 77.7
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
font: 15px sans-serif;
}

h1{
text-align: center;
color:#4CAF50;
font: 30px sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2{
text-align:center;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
fill: none;
stroke:black;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
fill: none;
stroke: steelblue;
stroke-width: 3px;
}

.overlay {
fill: none;
pointer-events: all;
}

.focus circle {
fill: none;
stroke: black;
}

</style>

<h1 id="Title">Commodity</h1>
<h2>
<select onchange="loadData()" id="metric">
<option value ="Glass">Glass ($/lbs)</option>
<option  value ="Aluminum">Aluminum ($/ton)</option>
</select>
</h2>

<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>


<script>
var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse,
    bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left,
    formatValue = d3.format(",.2f"),
    formatCurrency = function(d) { return "$" + formatValue(d); };

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.selectAll("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var loadData = function() {
var metric = document.getElementById('metric').selectedOptions[0].value;
var dataFile = metric + '.csv'
d3.csv(dataFile, function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
});

  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.date - b.date;
  });

// this tells DOM where to place the data 
  x.domain([data[0].date, data[data.length - 1].date]);
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

  var focus = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "focus")
      .style("display", "none");

  focus.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 8.5);

  focus.append("text")
      .attr("x", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em");

  svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "overlay")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
      .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
      .on("mousemove", mousemove);

  function mousemove() {
    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
        d0 = data[i - 1],
        d1 = data[i],
        d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.close) + ")");
    focus.selectAll("text").text(formatCurrency(d.close));
  }
})
}
loadData()
</script>
```

Comment: you should fix your demo first

Answer (score 0):

The reason that loading the second set adds a new path over the old path is due to this code:

```
svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

Instead of always appending a new path, you need to select the existing path element, and update its "d" attribute with the new path coming from your `line()` function. More information about this technique can be found at the [General Update Pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) pages.

Although I've not tested it, your code should be updated to something like this:

```
var path = svg.selectAll("path").datum(data);
path.enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line");
path.attr("d", line);
```

The `enter()` returns a selection of only those path elements that have not yet been created in the DOM. So the first time through, it appends a path element and sets its class. After that, no new path elements will be created. But in both cases, the "d" attr is set to be a line built from the data.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, Steve. I've inserted your snippet into mine but when I do that the path disappears altogether. I've tried tweaking it quite a bit based on the link you provided but still no dice. Do you think I need to add something along the lines of .path(function(d) { return d; }); somewhere?

Comment: What version of D3 are you using? My example works for me on d3v3, but you may have to use a `merge` selection.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function on `<select onchange="updateData()" id="metric">` event:

```
function updateData() {
  var metric = document.getElementById('metric').selectedOptions[0].text;
  var dataFile = 'data_' + metric + '.csv'
  d3.csv(dataFile, function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
      });

      // Scale the range of the data again 
      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    var svg = d3.select("body").transition();

    // Make the changes
        svg.select(".line")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", line(data));

        svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis);

    });
}
```